# Starting any process and suspending it lowers CPU from ~50% to ~5% in Vista, Why?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, cpu-usage, cpu-speed

While doing a little housekeeping on a Windows Vista installation, I discovered that suspending any winlogon.exe subprocess would lower the CPU usage from the normally observed 50% usage down to minimal usage. That is to say that Process Explorer would show the System Idle Process at 95% and above.
The same was not true for services.

Suspending anything started via the task manager or services does not result in this behaviour.

For example, I could simply start cmd.exe and suspend it. Then reported CPU% drops (and the fan slow and machine cools) 
Resuming OR killing the cmd.exe would result in CPU Usage back at ~50%

As this was a brief encounter with this laptop, I didn't note the make/model/CPU/OS version/service packs etc, so I accept that as lacking in the question.

I should also say that my personal answer to this question could be along the lines of
Why? - "Because scheduling (among other things) in Vista is severely broken."

But I am intrigued to know why suspending ANY (child of winlogon) process would have this effect.

Comment: capture a xperf trace (http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD) but use the Win7 SDK version (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt/revision/2.aspx), the Win8 version only work in 7/8. Start the trace and Capture the cpu usage before and after suspending the Winlogon.exe. zip and upload the file.

Comment: Are you in balanced power mode? Is it changing the CPU speed to max when you do that, so it appears as it is using less, when in reality it is using the same or more? What does cpuinfo report as the CPU speed before and after?